# How to parse XML elements?

Tags: c#, xml

I have an XML File that has this block in it. I am able to parse everything except the speed and watts.

This is the XML string:

```
"<Trackpoint>" + 
"<Time>2014-05-06T23:22:40.000Z</Time>" + 
"<Position>" + 
"<LatitudeDegrees>34.43368820473552</LatitudeDegrees>" + 
"<LongitudeDegrees>-84.17464644648135</LongitudeDegrees>" + 
"</Position>" + 
"<AltitudeMeters>377.79998779296875</AltitudeMeters>" + 
"<DistanceMeters>337.4100036621094</DistanceMeters>" + 
"<HeartRateBpm>" + 
"<Value>152</Value>" + 
"</HeartRateBpm>" + 
"<Cadence>107</Cadence>" + 
"<Extensions>" + 
"<TPX xmlns=\"http://www.garmin.com/xmlschemas/ActivityExtension/v2\">" + 
"<Speed>9.878000259399414</Speed>" + 
"<Watts>238</Watts>" +** 
"</TPX>" + 
"</Extensions>" + 
"</Trackpoint>" +
```

This is the code I am using to parse it:

```
select new TrackPointDTO {
                        Timex = trackPointElement.Element (ns1 + "Time") != null ? Convert.ToString ((string)trackPointElement.Element (ns1 + "Time").Value) : "",
                        AltitudeMeters = (decimal)(trackPointElement.Element (ns1 + "AltitudeMeters") != null ? Convert.ToDouble ((string)trackPointElement.Element (ns1 + "AltitudeMeters").Value) : 0.0),
                        DistanceMeters = (decimal)(trackPointElement.Element (ns1 + "DistanceMeters") != null ? Convert.ToDouble ((string)trackPointElement.Element (ns1 + "DistanceMeters").Value) : 0.0),
                        HeartRateBpm = trackPointElement.Element (ns1 + "HeartRateBpm") != null ? Convert.ToInt16 ((string)trackPointElement.Element (ns1 + "HeartRateBpm").Value) : 0,
                        Cadence = trackPointElement.Element (ns1 + "Cadence") != null ? Convert.ToInt16 ((string)trackPointElement.Element (ns1 + "Cadence").Value) : 0,

                                    SpeedPower = ((from speedPowerElement in trackPointElement.Descendants (ns1 + "Extensions").Descendants(ns1 + "TPX")
                                        select new SpeedPower {
                                            Speed = (double)Convert.ToDouble ((string)speedPowerElement.Element(ns1 + "Speed").Value),
                                            Power = (double)Convert.ToDouble ((string)speedPowerElement.Element (ns1 + "Watts").Value)
                                        })
                                        .ToList ()),


                        SensorState = trackPointElement.Element (ns1 + "SensorState") != null ? trackPointElement.Element (ns1 + "SensorState").Value : "",
                        Positionx = ((from positionElement in trackPointElement.Descendants (ns1 + "Position")
                            select new Position {
                            LatitudeDegrees = (double)Convert.ToDouble ((string)positionElement.Element (ns1 + "LatitudeDegrees").Value),
                            LongitudeDegrees = (double)Convert.ToDouble ((string)positionElement.Element (ns1 + "LongitudeDegrees").Value)
                        })
                            .ToList ())
```

I can't seem to get at the speed and power...any suggestions?

Comment: This is not a xml which you are parsing. E.g. `Time` does not have any namespace. Please give xml correlates with your code

Comment: Do you get some exception? What are culture settings for the thread that runs this?

Comment: @SergeyBerezovskiy: if `ns1` is an empty string ...?

Comment: @ThomasW. `ns1` used with `TPX` element as well, which has namespace delcared, so I assume this is a default namespace for this xml. But then two questions - why its explicitly added to `TPX` element, and why its missing in xml sample root

Comment: @SergeyBerezovskiy: Correct. Didn't spot this.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The TPX element (and its siblings) are in a different namespace. Therefore you need to initialize an additional XNamespace variable which you use for these elements instead of "ns1".

BTW, lines like these can be shortened using the explicit cast operations on XElement combined with the "null coalescing operator":

```
// This:
((string)trackPointElement.Element (ns1 + "Time").Value) : "",
(decimal)(trackPointElement.Element (ns1 + "AltitudeMeters") != null ? Convert.ToDouble ((string)trackPointElement.Element (ns1 + "AltitudeMeters").Value) : 0.0),

// is equivalent to:
(string)trackPointElement.Element (ns1 + "Time") ?? ""
(decimal?)trackPointElement.Element (ns1 + "AltitudeMeters") ?? 0.0,
```

Comment: XNamespace tpx = "http://www.garmin.com/xmlschemas/ActivityExtension/v2"; ....Descendants(tpx + "TPX")

Comment: So it should look like this?     SpeedPower = ((from speedPowerElement in ((IEnumerable<XElement>)trackPointElement.Descendants(tpx + "TPX"))
           select new SpeedPower {
            Speed = (double)Convert.ToDouble ((string)speedPowerElement.Element(ns1 + "Speed").Value)
            //Power = (double)Convert.ToDouble ((string)speedPowerElement.Element (ns1 + "Watts").Value)
           })
           .ToList ())

Comment: and how do I handle the Extensions descendant?

Comment: No, the items inside the TPX element are also in that namespace so you'll need to prefix these with that namespace also: tpx + "Speed"  and tpx + "Watts".

Answer (score 0):

You need to use the namespace for the `TPX` node using the [XNamespace.Get method](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.xml.linq.xnamespace.get%28v=vs.110%29.aspx). A possible solution could look like this:

```
var doc = XDocument.Parse(xml);
// create namespace of TPX
var ns = XNamespace.Get(@"http://www.garmin.com/xmlschemas/ActivityExtension/v2");
// get TPX node using the namespace
var tpx = doc.Root.Element("Extensions").Element(ns + "TPX");
// retrieve Speed and Watts using the namespace
var speed = tpx.Element(ns + "Speed");
var watts = tpx.Element(ns + "Watts");
Console.WriteLine("{0} - {1}", speed.Value, watts.Value);
```

The output is:

```
9.878000259399414 - 238
```